# How to Verify AWS Cognito user on Server (running on nodeJS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito User Pools to signup & signin  my users(client, iOS). My user's make calls to endpoints on the server running on NodeJS (EC2 Instance). How can I authenticate my users on the server (NodeJS) ?

One way that I see is, to generate a JWT token on the client side and pass it to the server along with the POST request and have it verified.

Is this possible using Cognito Userpools ? or Is there any better alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all AWS Cognito Userpools is able to generate the JWT token(id_token) once authenticated against the Userpool.

There are two ways to generate the JWT token.

- Using AWS Cognito Userpools Hosted UI you can can get the id_token. If you enable openid claim and use the implicit grant it will directly redirected to your defined URL from Cognito Login Page. If you use authorization code flow, you need to use backend code with AWS SDK and token endpoint.
- You can also use the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) and implement your custom login page where it generates the id_token using the SDK.

The id_token can be [verified at your API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) using a standard JWT verification library.